# Timed Availability of controls in tkinter GUI

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, raspberry-pi2

I'm working on a program that will stop users from changing a label after a random amount of time. There are two buttons, start and next, when the user presses start the start button is destroyed but is supposed to  come back after a randomly selected amount of time. I tried to have the start button trigger a flag that starts a timer. When the timer reaches a certain value (count_to+1) the flag should go to zero, the start button should reappear, and the label should read end. The flag never seems to switch and the timer never initiates though. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong? and maybe point me towards a solution? Hear is the code:

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
import random
import time

mGui = Tk()
mGui.geometry('450x450+200+200')
mGui.title('Letters')

stored = ['A', 'b', 'c', 'd']
count_down = [10,20,30,40,50,60]
global count_to
global countFlag
count_to = IntVar()
countFlag = 0
Sec = 0


def run_counter():
    count_to = random.choice(count_down)
    while countFlag == 1:
        Sec+=1
        print(sec)
        if Sec == count_to+1:
            countFlag = 0
            newbutton.destroy()
            startbutton.grid(row=2,column=1)
            phrase.configure(text='End')
    return

def change_phrase():
    fish = StringVar()
    fish = random.choice(stored)
    stored.remove(fish)
    phrase.configure(text=fish)
    #to help with debug
    print(countFlag)
    print(Sec)
    print(count_to)
    return

def start_count():
    countFlag = True
    count_to = random.choice(count_down)
    print(countFlag)
    startbutton.destroy()
    run_counter
    return


phrase = Label(mGui,text='Letter',fg='red',bg='blue')
phrase.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky=S,columnspan=2)


startbutton =Button(mGui, text='start',fg='black',bg='green',command=start_count)
startbutton.grid(row=2,column=1)
newbutton = Button(mGui,text='NEXT',fg='black',bg='red',command=change_phrase)
newbutton.grid(row=2,column=0)

#mEntry = Entry(mGui,textvariable=ment)
#mEntry.grid(row=3,column=0)

mGui.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter programming becomes much less messy and confusing once you learn to use classes.  Use Tkinter's after() method to call a function every "x" amount of time until the allotted time has elapsed.

```
import random
import sys

if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import Tkinter as tk     ## Python 2.x
else:
    import tkinter as tk     ## Python 3.x

class ButtonDisappear():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root=root
        self.startbutton=tk.Button(root, text='disappear', fg='black',
                                   bg='green', command=self.disappear)
        self.startbutton.grid(row=2,column=1)
        self.lab=tk.Label(self.root, text="", bg="lightblue")

    def disappear(self):
        ## remove button
        self.startbutton.grid_forget()
        ## grid label for time
        self.lab.grid(row=0, column=0)
        ## "random" number
        self.stop_time=random.choice([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])*1000
        self.elapsed=0
        self.root.after(100, self.time_it)

    def time_it(self):
        self.elapsed += 100
        ## function calls itself until time has finished
        if self.elapsed < self.stop_time:
            self.lab["text"]="%d of %d" % (self.elapsed, self.stop_time)
            self.root.after(100, self.time_it)
        ## time elapsed so remove label and restore button
        else:
            self.lab.grid_forget()
            self.startbutton.grid(row=2,column=1)


m_gui = tk.Tk()
m_gui.geometry('450x450+200+200')
m_gui.title('Letters')
B=ButtonDisappear(m_gui)
m_gui.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tried this but I received two errors, first was a bad geometry specifier, so I commented that out because I'm not too concerned with the geometry of the program at this point. The second one is pertaining to line 37: `B=ButtonDisappear(m_gui)`. I receive `TypeError: object._new_() takes no parameters`. Any idea what I could have done wrong? I'm using Python 3.

Comment: There is no way for me to tell what is in your code.